# Linear Regression And Finding The Region/Range It Applies

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have some data $(x_i,y_i)$ that I think should have a linear relationship but only within some unknown range $x \in (a,b)$.

Is there a way to fit a linear model to the dataset that finds the linear coefficients as well as the range over which they apply? And does anyone have any references for this? Or even just the right name for what I am trying to do?

Comment: You'll need to tighten things up a bit here: Do you mean $E(Y | X=x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$ for $x \in [a,b]$, otherwise $E(Y|X=x)$ is some unspecified function $f(x)$? Or do you want to allow $f(x)$ to have some function form, like quadratic? Do you want $f(x)$ to join the line so that $f(a) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 a$ and $f(b) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 b$? Do you want the function to be smoothly differentiable with $f'(a) = f'(b) = \beta_1$?

Comment: This sounds like a [tag:change-point] problem: follow the link to find related threads.

Comment: @BigBendRegion yeah $E(Y|X=x)=β0+β1x$ for $x∈[a,b]$, otherwise $E(Y|X=x)$ is some unspecified function $f(x)$? And yes I would like f(x) to join the line, but I don't care what form f(x) takes (although it is actually linear).